# PHP can't use compiled memcache.so extension

Tags: php, memcached

I have PHP 5.4.8 compiled from source on Ubuntu 12.04. PHP resides in a custom directory.

I compiled memcache-2.2.7 and I ended up with a memcache.so extension.

I modified my `php.ini` and added:

```
extension=/jusr/php5/ext/memcache.so
```

but when I run a test script on CLI i get an error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/jusr/php5/ext/memcache.so' - /jusr/php5/ext/memcache.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You should move your solution to its own answer and accept it so it's clearer to future visitors what happened.

Answer (score 4):

I have actually figured it out. What most "guides" out there won't tell you is that you need to link memcache with the php-config file located in your PHP installation.

```
cd /home/user/memcache-2.2.7
phpize --clean && phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/path/to/php/bin/php-config
make
make install
```

That is how you link memcache with PHP. I could not get this ANYWHERE.

Answer (score 0):

(From bugs.php.net)

*You've built the library using wrong PHP headers.
  Please make sure phpize and php-config in your system came with the version of PHP you're using.*

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57263

Comment: i already saw that link before i posted here. it tells me nothing